# Observable on map to detect when is added, updated of deleted an entry

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, delegates, observable, concurrenthashmap

I have a map, in my case a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Device>` which is updating when receiving some events on websocket. I want to implement an observable on this map to know when an entry is added, updated or deleted. I tried with an `ObservableProperty` but no methods are called when map is changed.

```
var deviceCache : ConcurrentHashMap<String, Device> by MyObservable(ConcurrentHashMap())

 class MyObservable<T, V>(initialValue: ConcurrentHashMap<T, V>) : ObservableProperty<ConcurrentHashMap<T, V>>(initialValue) {
override fun afterChange(property: KProperty<*>, oldValue: ConcurrentHashMap<T, V>, newValue: ConcurrentHashMap<T, V>) {
  super.afterChange(property, oldValue, newValue)
  log.e("new value is $newValue")
}

override fun beforeChange(property: KProperty<*>, oldValue: ConcurrentHashMap<T, V>, newValue: ConcurrentHashMap<T, V>): Boolean {
  log.e("beforeChange called")
  return super.beforeChange(property, oldValue, newValue)
}
```

}

Can anyone help me how can I solve this?

Comment: How does `MyObservable` look like?

Comment: @AdamArold it is in my question.

Comment: Oh, sorry I see it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `Map` is not a property, you can't use property delegates this way. What you have to do is to write a decorator for `Map` like this:

```
class ObservableMap<K, V>(private val map: MutableMap<K, V>) : MutableMap<K, V> by map {

    override fun put(key: K, value: V): V? {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

    override fun putAll(from: Map<out K, V>) {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

    override fun remove(key: K): V? {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

}
```

Here we delegate all operations to the backing `map` and you just only have to implement your logic when adding/deleting in the methods above.

I'm not sure what you mean by `update` but if you mean "a value in the map gets overwritten" than you can handle it in `put`.

You can use this `ObservableMap` like this:

```
val map = ObservableMap(ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>())
```

Note that if you want to support the operations of `ConcurrentHashMap` you also need to include `overrides` for `AbstractMap<K,V>` and `ConcurrentMap<K,V>` since they add some new operations you might want to track. The code above is just an example.

Comment: Thank you, it works very nice. One more question: I have this cache on service layer (it is a java-library module). I need to send these notifications (when is added, updated or removed) to presentation layer (android-layer), in a viewModel. The only solution I see is to use listeners. Is it possible using this decorator to inform the UI about these changes? The service layer doesn't know about the presentation layer, only the presentation layer knows about service layer.

Comment: I'd use an event bus probably. Have you tried [this one](https://android.jlelse.eu/rxbus-kotlin-listen-where-ever-you-want-e6fc0760a4a8)?

Comment: No, I must to implement with no libraries.

Comment: You can write one easily. [Here](https://github.com/Hexworks/cobalt/tree/master/cobalt.events/common/src/main/kotlin/org/hexworks/cobalt/events/api) is an example.